# Divs being hidden behind content, need to push it down

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty much at wits end right about now and can't seem to figure out why my divs aren't pushing content down on the page. If you go to http://www.wilwaldon.com/itsbroken/template.php  you'll notice that the thumbnails on the right side are getting hidden behind the content below them.

I'd like the thumbnails to push the bottom content down as opposed to being behind it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and you'd pretty much save my brain from exploding at this point.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I would try following:

Try to exclude the "" from "videoplayerwrap" and rather put it on the same level in your HTML tree, so instead of:

```
#videoselectwrap
#videoplayerwrap
 - #videoplayertop
 - #videoplayercenter
 - #videoplayerbottom
 - #video_bottom
```

will be:

```
#videoselectwrap
#videoplayerwrap
 - #videoplayertop
 - #videoplayercenter
 - #videoplayerbottom
#video_bottom
```

Also, put `<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>"` immediately before closing tag of `#video_bottom`.

That *should* work :]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your videopageprofile and videoresourceswrapper are nested inside video_bottom. I suggest pulling them out of video_bottom and putting them in a separate div nested in videoplayerwrap.